# Make an object exists in all templates

Tags: python, django, templates, variables

I have a django and I wrote some views. I know how to pass my variables to template, but I also has some external modules with their own views, which I wont modify. 
Please help me understand how can I get one of my object "Menu.objects.all()" exist in all templates? 
So for example a I have django-registration and i want to have all my menu items appear at top when someone visits not my app url. I mean it will be registration app url, which returns templateresponse (and here I dont have my variable).

Answer (score 1):

You can add variables to context

Comment: like this: http://rubayeet.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/django-how-to-make-a-variable-available-in-all-templates/

Comment: That's a great article. Just be sure to read the comments for corrections.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do it, is to use a Template Context Processor, which is a hook that will allow you to add things to your context before the template is rendered.

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Here's an example of Template Context Processors used in the django core:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/context_processors.py